# Run a linux vm from shell on windows

Tags: linux, windows, virtual-machine

My friend has a windows pc and wants to run linux software on it - without a GUI. How can he run a Linux virtual machine from the Windows command prompt?

Comment: Can you be me specific about what you want to do? If you are asking about running a CLI ("server") version of Linux inside a virtual machine on a Windows host, then yes that is very much possible. OTOH if you want to run a unix-like *shell* inside a Windows `cmd` prompt, then you should probably be looking at things like cygwin and mingw.

Comment: Why does the VM need to be run from the WIndows command prompt? His Windows install will have a GUI. If you want a GUI-less Linux in a VM, just install one. Why fiddle with the Windows prompt at all?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are asking, but I'm guessing you want to run a Linux VM machine on a windows machine, but don't want the Linux to have the GUI.

You would need to install/download a version of Linux without the GUI. If using the Ubuntu flavour, try the server version since it doesn't contain the GUI.

I found a similar [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270435/how-to-run-ubuntu-without-gui-in-virtual-box)

Answer (score 0):

[Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) is a framework that controls other virtual machine systems such as Virtualbox.

If your friend is technically inclined, they should be able to install Virtualbox then Vagrant.

Vagrant can then be used to bring up VMs from the command line.

If Vagrant looks to be too complex for your friend's needs, then Virtualbox has a lot of [command line options](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html).  A quick glance at the options shows me that you can run "VBoxManage startvm" to start up a VM.